# JavaScript startsWith using regex & offset

Tags: javascript, regex, string, performance, regex-group

I'm doing some string parsing and would like to use regexes. I am iterating through strings and would like to apply something like "startsWith" using a regex and an offset, returning a match if its found or null if not. In pseudo-javascript :

```
function startsWith(string, regex, offset) {
    if (regex_matches_at_offset) {
        return match;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

A simple and straightforward solution is to first apply substring and then match. But I want something like "startsWith" using a regex.

If it was a string instead of a regex, I'd go with [startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp)

```
function startsWith(string, other_string, offset) {
    let starts_with=s.startsWith(other_string, offset); // startsWith from position offset onwards, as other_string has fixed length the "match" is also known
    if (starts_with) {
        return other_string; // other_string = match
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But for regexes, my current solution (for testing purposes only) looks like :

```
function startsWith(string, regex, offset) {
    let end_part=s.substring(offset); // Substring, performance issue
    let match=end_part.match(regex); // Match it as we need the match
    if (match.length === 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        match=match[0]; // Only care about 1st match
    }
    if (end_part.startsWith(match)) { // Check if match already starts at first position
        return match;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which is not very satisfying as there are obvious problems (copying most of the string, performing the regex search twice...

Expected :

1. Find regex in string starting from given position, not only boolean but also match
2. High performance (do not copy entire string, for example)

Examples :

```
startsWith("Hello world !", /h/i, 0); // "H"
startsWith("Hello world !", /wor?/i, 6); // "wor"
startsWith("Hello world !", /wor?/i, 10); // null
startsWith("Hello world !", /z/i, 0); // null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to build an regex based on offset and pattern passed as string

- Here initial part of regex uses `.` to match any character upto offset
- Second use passed pattern in captured group to return only desired match

```js
let startsWith = (str, reg, offset) =>{
  let regex = `^.{${0,offset}}(${reg})`
  let final = new RegExp(regex,'i')
  let found = str.match(final)
  console.log(found ? found[1] : found)
}

startsWith("Hello world !", 'h', 0); // "H"
startsWith("Hello world !", 'wor?', 6); // "wor"
startsWith("Hello world !", 'wor?', 10); // null
startsWith("Hello world !", 'z', 0); // null
```

As mentioned by [@mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) we can use [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) property to if we want regex to be passed as argument to function

```js
let startsWith = (str, reg, offset) =>{
  let regex = `^.{${0,offset}}(${reg.source})`
  let final = new RegExp(regex,'i')
  let found = str.match(final)
  console.log(found ? found[1] : found)
}

startsWith("Hello world !", /h/i, 0); // "H"
startsWith("Hello world !", /wor?/i, 6); // "wor"
startsWith("Hello world !", /wor?/i, 10); // null
startsWith("Hello world !", /z/i, 0); // null
```

Comment: You could consider using the regex property [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) to pull out a string which would allow the function to accept regular expressions rather than strings.

Comment: @MarkMeyer didn't knew about that let me read and update, thanks for info

Comment: It seems to work with these examples, but I'm not sure if it will create difficult edge cases.

Comment: Giving it a second thought, is there a way that doesn't incur the cost of RegEx compilation?